# Unable to replace NSArray derived from output of "ps aux" UNIX command

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Im trying to replace the 7th index of the array "lines2". The NSMUTABLEARRAY "lines2" is derived from the UNIX command "ps aux", and I suspect that this command returns an array of NSCFStrings. Im basically trying to replace "Ss" with "Ss (Running)" for now. The problem is that I get a SIGABRT error every time The program reaches the part where it tries to replace the particular array element. The code for my viewController is below.

```
NSLog(@"myString is :%@", myString);
int processID = [myString intValue];

NSTask *task;
task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/ps"];

arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"aux", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", processID],nil];

[task setArguments: arguments];

NSPipe *pipe;
pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
//[task setStandardOutput: pipe];
[task setStandardOutput:pipe];

NSFileHandle *file;
file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

[task launch];

NSData *data;
data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

NSString *string;
string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data
                               encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//  NSLog(@"%@",string);


NSArray *lines= [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

NSString *lastline = [lines objectAtIndex:[lines count]-2];
//  NSLog(@"%@",lastline);



lines2= [lastline componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSLog(@"%@",lines2);
for (int i=0; i<[lines2 count]; i++) {

    if([[lines2 objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@""]){
        [lines2 removeObjectAtIndex:i];
    }

}
for (int i=0; i<[lines2 count]; i++) {

    if([[lines2 objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@""]){
        [lines2 removeObjectAtIndex:i];
    }

}
for (int i=0; i<[lines2 count]; i++) {

    if([[lines2 objectAtIndex:7] isEqualToString:@"Ss"]){
        [[lines2 objectAtIndex:0] replaceObjectAtIndex:7 withObject:@"SS (Running)"];

    }
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at the documentation for the method [-componentsSeparatedByString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-componentsSeparatedByString_).  The signature is:

```
- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator
```

Notice the return type is `NSArray`.  This is an **immutable** object.  You **must not** change it even if inspecting the returned object (say with a debugger or an NSLog) shows it to actually be mutable.  You **must** [respect the API contract](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW63). (Read the section of the link entitled "receiving mutable objects".)

That said, the immediate cause of your error is this line:

```
[[lines2 objectAtIndex:0] replaceObjectAtIndex:7 withObject:@"SS (Running)"];
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This is wrong
```

`lines2` is an array of strings. `[lines2 objectAtIndex: 0]` is a string.  Why are you sending `-replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` to it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what the error you're seeing is, but you cannot change the values in the NSArray because an `NSArray` is an immutable container.

Use an `NSMutableArray` when you want to make modifications. If you have an NSArray already (as in the return value from `-componentsSeparatedByString:`), you can get a mutable array by doing this:

```
NSMutableArray * myMutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:lines2];
```

Comment: Actually its an NSMutableArray, I forgot to mention that. I think its throwing a SIGABRT because im trying to replace an NSCFString (the output of ps aux) with an NSString.

Answer (score 0):

`NSArray` is not mutable. First copy it to an `NSMutableArray` (e.g. using `[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:]`) so you can manipulate it.

Didn't you get any warnings during compilation?

Comment: Sorry it should be NSMutableArray, I typed it wrongly. It still throws this exception :

Comment: -[NSCFString replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b25b70
2011-08-23 15:27:10.224 TableViewController_09[3376:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b25b70'